# What are common notations for the endomorphism group of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Given a vector space $V$, the set of endomorphisms in $V$ can be denoted
$$\text{End}(V)=\left\{L:V\rightarrow V:L\text{ is linear}\right\},$$
particularly when one wants to be completely unambiguous. However, few entry-level linear algebra textbooks use this notation; I remember [Friedberg, Insel and Spence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130084514) using the notation $$L(V)$$ and while I can't think of any others I am sure they exist. What are some common notations for this object, and who uses them?

Comment: $\mathcal L(V,V)$

Answer (score 1):

I have seen $\text{Hom}(V,W)$ and $L(V,W)$ for the set of linear maps $V\to W$, i.e. $\text{End}(V)$ would be $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ or $L(V,V)$.

Comment: If one wants to specify the field, one can write $\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,W)$. As an example we can write $V^*=\operatorname{Hom}_F(V,F)$.

Comment: Yes, although normally the field should be known from the context.